# Can a Jewish news-provider purposefully lie to Jews?

Tags: halacha, sheker-false, publications

Over this summer, I have seen a number of websites claiming to be Jewish newssites disseminating blatantly false information, particularly about Israel. Whether or not these sites represent Israeli interests is not important, but is it halachically viable for a news-source to knowingly spread misinformation?

Comment: Would you be willing to share an example of this phenomenon? It may not help answer the question, but it would let us know that it really happens.

Comment: Jewsnews.co.il is the first and most egregious that comes to mind, although Israel HaYom also does this (according to both Naftali Bennett and Yitzchak Herzog)

Comment: jewsnews is what the industry calls "clickbait"; sensationalized headlines designed to get you to click on the page, so they can charge for ads on the site.  It has no journalistic integrity, and I doubt it's even really Jewish owned.  Israel Hayom is different matter entirely; it is a real news operation, but has a pro-Likud editorial slant.  Bennett was mad at them for repeating Netanyahu's plans and ideas in their newspaper, without offering an alternate [read: Bennett's] point of view.

Comment: related:  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4634/6893